# Creating parallax focus effect on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, tvos

How do you create the parallax focus effect on a collection view cell with a custom view?  If I were using an image view the property to set would be `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` but my collection view cell contains a subclassed `UIView` with custom content drawn using core graphics.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is it supposed to look like? A video or a gif...

Comment: I don't think there is an easy, built-in way of doing this. The only thing I can think of is adding a gesture recognizer, and then modifying a layer's transform for each view that you want to move. And then set it back to identity transform when cell goes out of focus. But that seems to be an overkill.

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @raulriera is nice, but only shifts the cell around in 2D.
Also, the OP asked for an objective-C example.

I was also looking to do this effect for the exact same reason - I had UICollectionView with cells containing images and labels.

I created a UIMotionEffectGroup subclass, since getting near to the Apple TV effect seems to require four different motion effects. The first two are the flat movements as in @raulriera, and the other two are the 3D rotations.

Just the shiny environment layer to go now. Any takers? :-)

Here is my code for the motion effect group:

(The shiftDistance and tiltAngle constants set the magnitude of the effect. The given values look pretty similar to the Apple TV effect.)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIAppleTvMotionEffectGroup.h"

@implementation UIAppleTvMotionEffectGroup

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil)
    {
        // Size of shift movements
        CGFloat const shiftDistance = 10.0f;

        // Make horizontal movements shift the centre left and right
        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *xShift = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
                                              initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"
                                              type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
        xShift.minimumRelativeValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: shiftDistance * -1.0f];
        xShift.maximumRelativeValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: shiftDistance];

        // Make vertical movements shift the centre up and down
        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *yShift = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
                                              initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
                                              type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
        yShift.minimumRelativeValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: shiftDistance * -1.0f];
        yShift.maximumRelativeValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: shiftDistance];

        // Size of tilt movements
        CGFloat const tiltAngle = M_PI_4 * 0.125;

        // Now make horizontal movements effect a rotation about the Y axis for side-to-side rotation.
        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *xTilt = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"layer.transform" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];

        // CATransform3D value for minimumRelativeValue
        CATransform3D transMinimumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transMinimumTiltAboutY.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
        transMinimumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DRotate(transMinimumTiltAboutY, tiltAngle * -1.0, 0, 1, 0);

        // CATransform3D value for maximumRelativeValue
        CATransform3D transMaximumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transMaximumTiltAboutY.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
        transMaximumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DRotate(transMaximumTiltAboutY, tiltAngle, 0, 1, 0);

        // Set the transform property boundaries for the interpolation
        xTilt.minimumRelativeValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transMinimumTiltAboutY];
        xTilt.maximumRelativeValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transMaximumTiltAboutY];

        // Now make vertical movements effect a rotation about the X axis for up and down rotation.
        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *yTilt = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"layer.transform" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];

        // CATransform3D value for minimumRelativeValue
        CATransform3D transMinimumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transMinimumTiltAboutX.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
        transMinimumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DRotate(transMinimumTiltAboutX, tiltAngle * -1.0, 1, 0, 0);

        // CATransform3D value for maximumRelativeValue
        CATransform3D transMaximumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transMaximumTiltAboutX.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
        transMaximumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DRotate(transMaximumTiltAboutX, tiltAngle, 1, 0, 0);

        // Set the transform property boundaries for the interpolation
        yTilt.minimumRelativeValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transMinimumTiltAboutX];
        yTilt.maximumRelativeValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transMaximumTiltAboutX];

        // Add all of the motion effects to this group
        self.motionEffects = @[xShift, yShift, xTilt, yTilt];

        [xShift release];
        [yShift release];
        [xTilt release];
        [yTilt release];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I used it like this in my custom UICollectionViewCell subclass:

```
@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    // Create a static instance of the motion effect group (could do this anywhere, really, maybe init would be better - we only need one of them.)
    static UIAppleTVMotionEffectGroup *s_atvMotionEffect = nil;
    if (s_atvMotionEffect == nil)
    {
        s_atvMotionEffect = [[UIAppleTVMotionEffectGroup alloc] init];
    }

    [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations: ^{
        if (self.focused)
        {
            [self addMotionEffect: s_atvMotionEffect];
        }
        else
        {
            [self removeMotionEffect: s_atvMotionEffect];
        }

                               completion: ^{

            }];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have always had problems implementing the 3DTransform. It seems the text get clipped when I move around the cell :/

Comment: You should disable clipping for the cell. Set clipstobounds to false.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem there seems to be a z ordering issue. Looks like the image and text are being set at almost the same z position, so the image texture is obscuring the text at certain angles. Solution for that is to apply a translation in z to the text object, to keep it a little above the image.

Comment: You are correct, that was it... thanks! didn't even think about that

Comment: views becoming pixelated on applying 3D transforms.

Comment: I've converted this to swift 3.0.  To avoid cluttering the comments I've posted it as a separate answer.  See below.  Great solution thanks

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is add a UIMotionEffect to your subviews. Something like this

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ [unowned self] in
        if self.focused {
            let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
            verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -10
            verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 10

            let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
            horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -10
            horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 10

            let motionEffectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()
            motionEffectGroup.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]

            yourView.addMotionEffect(motionEffectGroup)
        }
        else {
            // Remove the effect here
        }
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: how to remove motion effect.

Answer (score 6):

I've converted Simon Tillson's answer to swift 3.0 and posted here to save typing for people in the future.  Thanks very much for a great solution.

```
class UIAppleTVMotionEffectGroup : UIMotionEffectGroup{
// size of shift movements
let shiftDistance : CGFloat = 10.0
let tiltAngle : CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI_4) * 0.125

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    // Make horizontal movements shift the centre left and right
    let xShift = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    xShift.minimumRelativeValue = shiftDistance * -1.0
    xShift.maximumRelativeValue = shiftDistance

    let yShift = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    yShift.minimumRelativeValue = 0.0-shiftDistance
    yShift.maximumRelativeValue = shiftDistance

    let xTilt = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)

    var transMinimumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DIdentity
    transMinimumTiltAboutY.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0
    transMinimumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DRotate(transMinimumTiltAboutY, tiltAngle * -1.0, 0, 1, 0)

    var transMaximumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DIdentity
    transMaximumTiltAboutY.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0
    transMaximumTiltAboutY = CATransform3DRotate(transMaximumTiltAboutY, tiltAngle , 0, 1, 0)

    xTilt.minimumRelativeValue = transMinimumTiltAboutY
    xTilt.maximumRelativeValue = transMaximumTiltAboutY

    let yTilt = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform", type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.tiltAlongVerticalAxis)

    var transMinimumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DIdentity
    transMinimumTiltAboutX.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0
    transMinimumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DRotate(transMinimumTiltAboutX, tiltAngle * -1.0, 1, 0, 0)

    var transMaximumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DIdentity
    transMaximumTiltAboutX.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0
    transMaximumTiltAboutX = CATransform3DRotate(transMaximumTiltAboutX, tiltAngle , 1, 0, 0)

    yTilt.minimumRelativeValue = transMinimumTiltAboutX
    yTilt.maximumRelativeValue = transMaximumTiltAboutX

    self.motionEffects = [xShift,yShift,xTilt,yTilt]

}
```

}

I have added a little pop to the part in the UICollectionView subclass.  Note the struct wrapper for the static variable

```
  override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    struct wrapper {
        static let s_atvMotionEffect = UIAppleTVMotionEffectGroup()
    }


    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations( {
        var scale : CGFloat = 0.0
        if self.isFocused {
            self.addMotionEffect(wrapper.s_atvMotionEffect)
            scale = 1.2
        } else {
            self.removeMotionEffect(wrapper.s_atvMotionEffect)
            scale = 1.0
        }
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
    },completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: How happy I was to find this answer! Works well, but I have one question. When a cell is active it appears to drop behind its adjacent cells in the collection view which is the opposite of the normal tvOS effect. Why is this happening, and what can be done to fix?

Comment: An issue one runs into with this approach appease break the selection animation for the UICollectionView.